# iOS: Fetched results controller in separate views. How to update the other if one changes?

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two views with basically the same fetchedResults Controller. Or lets say with the same "query" from the database. One is to edit the data, the other one only shows the data. Now, if I change the date in the first view controller, my second view doesn't get updated. If I add these lines of codes in my display view:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear: (BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    self.budgetDatabase = nil;
}
```

it works. It always refetches if the view reappears and shows the new data (unfortunately with some lag due to the fetch). However my app crashes if you change too fast between the view controllers because probably this deleting and new setting of the database and fetched results controller is not as fast. 
So how can I still update my display view when some changes occur in my edit view? A [self.tableview reloadTableView] didn't work...

Comment: The table view should be updated automatically if the FRC delegate methods are implemented properly. - Perhaps show the FRC creation code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving your data model out of your controllers.  This becomes especially useful when you have multiple controllers that want access to the same data.  Instead of having to coordinate updates, keep a single consistent version of the data in the model and let the controllers get what they need for display.

The model can either be owned by a singleton object or an object that's relatively global and accessed through the app delegate.  (I like option #1 but either can work.)

Comment: I do not really understand this answer. As I understand it, each view controller accesses the data using a fetched results controller (which is a standard pattern), and the data itself is stored in managed object context and a Core Data persistent store.

Comment: I was responding to the idea that there are multiple fetched results controllers representing the same query.  If the FRC is treated as part of the data model it simplifies synchronizing visual representations.  Once you have things like `self.fetchedResultsController` and `self.budgetDatabase` at the controller layer it seems to me that you're mixing the M and C portions of MVC.  (Apple's sample code is typically terrible in this regard and often stuffs things that belong in the model into controllers.)

Comment: Ok now I see what you mean. But a FRC with its delegate methods is tightly bound to a single table view, and multiple table view controllers should not share a FRC (in my opinion).

Comment: I've done it exactly as Martin says. I don't understand your answer Phillip?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can just use view containment and remove the need for setting up 2 separate FRC for both of your view controller's?  It would probably simplify a lot of your headache here.

A good article can be found here: [objc.io - Issue #1 Lighter View Controllers](http://www.objc.io/issue-1/containment-view-controller.html)  I believe the "second" issue shows how to work with a tableviewcontroller if you're using that.  There is another article showing CollectionViewController's as well.. (along with Core Data)